# How can I query the deposit in DOT to create an HRMP channel?

Tags: xcm, xcmp, hrmp

I'm looking in the Developers>Storage>hrmp tab but I can't find the option to check the current minimum to create an HRMP channel. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You actually need to go to "Developer" > "Chain State" to check for the HRMP deposit. The function to call is `activeConfig()` under the `configuration` pallet. You'll see the `hrmpSenderDeposit` and the `hrmpRecipientDeposit` there, all in plancks:

[image: Picture of the chain state tab on Polkadot.js]

Do note that there is an [ongoing referendum](https://polkadot.polkassembly.io/referendum/61) now to lower the deposit substantially.

Comment: Thanks Keith, yes I am aware of that referendum (this information is to increase my knowledge :)